# Why is this BufferedReader returning empty String instead of null?

Tags: java, null, bufferedreader, string

I have a BufferedReader iterating through the lines of a CSV file; when it gets to the end of the file, it returns the following error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:992)`

How do I get the reader to realize it reached the end of file and input is null instead of empty? I've checked the file and there is no whitespace at the end of the last line.

Code:

```
    File filReadMe = new File(inputFile);
    BufferedReader brReadMe = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filReadMe), "UTF-8"));

    try
    {
        String strLine;

        while ((strLine = brReadMe.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(strLine);
            //place the line into CsvRecordFactory
            int record = csv.processLine(strLine, input); 
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        //Close the BufferedReader
        try {
            if (brReadMe != null)
                brReadMe.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The last line of your file contains an empty `String`, so you should check if `strLine.equals("")` as another condition to stop the `while-loop`.

Comment: strLine.isEmpty() would be better, semantically, than strLine.equals("")

Comment: Thanks Luiggi and Cyrille. Do you know what's wrong with my syntax by any chance? I'm still seeing the same error. 
while ((strLine = brReadMe.readLine()) != null && !strLine.isEmpty())

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza - `"".equals(strLine)` is usually preferable to avoid a potential NPE if strLine is `null`.

Comment: Try changing `System.out.println(strLine);` to             `System.out.println("\"" + strLine + "\"");` to help confirm the value of each line retrieved from the file.

Comment: @JoshDM that would be good but the `while-loop` already checks if `strLine` is different from `null`.

Comment: Thanks Josh. I took out that line completely but it still gives me the same error. I'll try create a SSCCE as mentioned by Cyrille

Answer (score 1):

You can simply modify your code this way:

```
while ((strLine = brReadMe.readLine()) != null)
{
    if (!strLine.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(strLine);
        //place the line into CsvRecordFactory
        int record = csv.processLine(strLine, input); 
    }
}
```

This way, your code will ignore all empty lines, not only those at the end of your file.

Comment: Thanks for that Cyrille. Makes perfect sense. My code must be doing something strange though as I'm still seeing the same error even after making the recommended changes.

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem in a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so we can have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the help all. I was editing the code to create an SSCCE as requested and found that when I removed the int record = csv.processLine(strLine, input); line, I no longer have the error. I'll take a look at it to see what it's up to. Thank you all for the extremely fast and really helpful tips.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't the end of file. The problem is that you are processing a blank line as though it wasn't blank. That could conceivably happen anywhere, not just as a final line before EOF. Check the line for emptiness before you start parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

if the end of your file is a newline, try backspacing it to the end of the previous line and see if you still get the error

Comment: This is more a hack than a solution =\.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give it a small *if* condition to check whether the string is empty or not.

Version 1: Check if string is empty

```
  while ((strLine = brReadMe.readLine()) != null)
    {
          if(!strLine.isEmpty()){
              System.out.println(strLine);
              //place the line into CsvRecordFactory
              int record = csv.processLine(strLine, input); 
          }
    }
```

I also have version 2 of code, which checks if string is number otherwise if they are characters or empty or anything else, the code inside *if* is going be ignored

```
while ((strLine = brReadMe.readLine()) != null)
        {
              if(strLine.matches("\\d+")){
                  System.out.println(strLine);
                  //place the line into CsvRecordFactory
                  int record = csv.processLine(strLine, input); 
              }
        }
```

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. eclipse threw a tantrum when i entered the regular expression and it took me a while to figure it out. option 1 returns the same error for me, and I can't test option 2 unfortunately.